# Is there a way to say match 1 or more instances of a defined subsequence/grouping?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'differ'

original = "Epic lolcat fail bellmead drive!"  
current = "Epic wolfman fail bellmead dr!"

diff = Differ.diff_by_word(current, original).to_s   

puts diff # => "Epic {"lolcat" >> "wolfman"} fail bellmead {"drive" >> "dr"}!

diff =~ /(\{"[a-zA-Z0-9]*" >> "[a-zA-Z0-9s]*"\})/

puts "#{$1} to #{$2} #{$3} to #{$4}"
# => lolcat to wolfman to

# Desired output: lolcat to wolfman to drive to dr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know 'differ', but how about:

```
require 'rubygems'  
require 'differ'

original = "Epic lolcat fail bellmead drive!"  
current = "Epic wolfman fail bellmead dr!"

diff = Differ.diff_by_word(current, original).to_s   

puts diff # => "Epic {"lolcat" >> "wolfman"} fail bellmead {"drive" >> "dr"}!

captures = diff.scan /\{"([a-zA-Z0-9]*)" >> "([a-zA-Z0-9s]*)"\}/

captures.each {|c| puts "#{c[0]} to #{c[1]}" }
```

Comment: Um...scan passes an array back doesn't it. Yes indeed it does. Thanks Adrian.